# Break line after n matches of a certain string in vim

Tags: regex, vim

Let the next string `aaaa, bbb, ccc, iii, hdjhda90., jjsjkasjaks, 00-01`. I would like a help to break this line after n matches of ",". For example for n=2 I expect

```
aaaa, bbb, 
ccc, iii, 
hdjhda90., jjsjkasjaks, 
00-01
```

I tried using \{n,m} without sucess

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to record a macro:

```
qq2f,a<CR>
```

- `2f,` moves the cursor to the second comma in the line
- `a<CR>` (where `<CR>` is you pressing 'return') breaks the line

The you can do `999@q` to repeat the macro to break up the line.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it if I felt like doing it with a substitution:

```
:s/,.\{-},\zs /\r
```

The pattern matches a `,`, followed by any character, as few as possible of it, followed by a `,` and a  . The trick is to ignore whatever comes before the   with `:help \zs` so that only the   is replaced.

The   is replaced with a newline.

But, frankly, I would probably use `:help /`, `:help c`, and `:help gn` instead:

```
/, <CR>
ncgn,<CR><Esc>
nn.
nn.
```